# Read in command line arguments from DrRacket

Tags: command-line, arguments, racket

How do I detect what command line arguments where given when a script is run with racket? That is, the equivalent of sys.argv in Python, args[] in Java, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have these choices (you can look them all up in the docs for more info):

- `current-command-line-arguments` -- a vector holding the command line arguments
- You can start a script with the `-m` flag, which will require the file and look for a provided `main` function, then apply it on the command-line arguments (as a list of strings)
- Or you can require `racket/cmdline` which provides a macro that can be used to define several flags in a convenient way.