# Get certain arguments from argv in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, command-line-arguments, argv

Hello I want to make a script that can be run like: `./hello.rkt my_name` and it'd print `hello my_name` and if nothing is passed: `Usage: {filename} <name>` where `{filename}` is the actual file name (`argv[0]`) but for that I need to get arguments from [current-command-line-arguments](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/runtime.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._current-command-line-arguments%29%29), but the solutions I found on how to extract an item from an array didn't work, I kept getting [contract violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20254274/error-contract-violation-in-scheme) errors and couldn't figure out how to make it work. So here's the code I have now:

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(define name "a")  ;; Should extract argv[1]

(if (regexp-match-exact? #px"\\S" name) (begin
    (display "hello ")
    (display name)
    (newline)
) (begin
    (display "usage: {FILENAME} <name>")  ;; TODO: replace {FILENAME} with argv[0]
    (newline)
    (exit 1)
))
```

**UPDATE**

The fix was to use `(vector-ref (current-command-line-arguments) N)` where N is the argument (NOTE: argv[0] is not the filename, but the 1st argument)

Comment: use `command-line` which makes this painless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read in command line arguments from DrRacket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713344/read-in-command-line-arguments-from-drracket)

Comment: @Barmar no, I don't want any flags like --name, i want pure argv

Comment: @ignis volens  i'll check it out

Comment: @ignis volens  Sorry, I don't want any flags, i just want to pass it raw :)

Comment: `current-command-line-arguments` doesn't include flags that are interpreted by racket itself.

Comment: See https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/runtime.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._current-command-line-arguments%29%29

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238706/discussion-between-ari157-and-barmar).